# Mocha framework not working when tested in AWS Lambda function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, mocha.js

I'm trying to run basic unit tests on AWS lambda through the Mocha testing framework. I'm running the tests programmatically through my handler method which works locally by outputting the correct test results, but when I test it on the Amazon servers, it only cooperates with certain features of the framework. For instance, when I run the handler method on AWS, it steps into the `describe` method, but 'skips' the `it` & `beforeEach` methods. I cannot seem to figure out why. If anyone has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it.

**handler.js**

```js
'use strict';
const path = require('path');
const glob = require("glob");

module.exports.addOne = async (event) => 
{
  const Mocha = require('mocha');
  const mocha = new Mocha();

  const testDir = '/var/task/aws-addOne/tests';
  const testFiles = glob.sync('**/*.test.js', {cwd: testDir});
  testFiles.forEach((file) => delete require.cache[file]);
  testFiles.forEach((file) => mocha.addFile(path.join(testDir, file)));

  mocha.run(() => { console.log('OK'); });
};
```

**login.test.js**

```js
const assert = require('assert');

describe('Login test suite', () =>
{
    console.log('flag #0');

    beforeEach(() =>
    {
        console.log('Hits beforeEach -- !'); 
    });

    it('test 1', () =>
    {
        console.log('flag #1');
        assert.equal(1, 1);
    });

    it('test 2', () =>
    {
        console.log('flag #2');
        assert.equal(1, 2);
    });
});
```

**AWS Output**

```
Response:
null

Request ID:
"a0fa18c3-67b8-4961-bbdb-2598839e6a57"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: a0fa18c3-67b8-4961-bbdb-2598839e6a57 Version: $LATEST
2020-03-03T19:57:22.699Z    a0fa18c3-67b8-4961-bbdb-2598839e6a57    INFO    flag #0
2020-03-03T19:57:22.701Z    a0fa18c3-67b8-4961-bbdb-2598839e6a57    INFO    undefined
2020-03-03T19:57:22.701Z    a0fa18c3-67b8-4961-bbdb-2598839e6a57    INFO    
2020-03-03T19:57:22.703Z    a0fa18c3-67b8-4961-bbdb-2598839e6a57    INFO      Login test suite
END RequestId: a0fa18c3-67b8-4961-bbdb-2598839e6a57
```

Comment: I'm confused about what you are trying to do here. Why is your lambda running tests?

Comment: I'll eventually be putting selenium scripts in these tests, but for now I just need to get the framework working when I invoke the Lambda function.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off using CodeBuild for that?

Comment: We're trying to reduce costs, but it is an alternative. I've gotten everything else in the project to work, including getting the necessary chrome binaries so that I could run the scripts in the container. I just can't figure out why mocha would skip over these methods.

Comment: The problem you are running into is that the function code exists immediately after calling `mocha.run()`. I don't know enough about how mocha works to help you find a solution, but the issue is that you either need to not use an async function and have a callback that triggers when done, or you need to be able to return a promise (`await`) the call to run mocha.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth Removing `async` from the handler did the trick! Thanks for taking the time, Jason. I realize I need to get better with promises..